# Android microphone buffers always half empty?

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to fill a buffer with microphone input and analyze the contents. I create my buffers with:

```
    int bufferSize=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    short[] buffer1 = new short[bufferSize];
```

Then in a separate class called Recorder, I have the following relevant code:

```
public short[] fillBuffer(short[] audioData, int bufferSize) {

    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize); // instantiate the
                                                            // AudioRecorder

    if (recorder.getRecordingState() == android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
        recorder.startRecording(); // check to see if the Recorder
                                    // has stopped or is not
                                    // recording, and make it
                                    // record.

    recorder.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize); // read the PCM
                                                // audio data
                                                // into the
                                                // audioData
                                                // array

    if (recorder.getState() == android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)
        recorder.stop(); // stop the recorder

    return audioData;

}
```

Then, when I call:

```
recorder.fillBuffer(buffer1, bufferSize);
```

and log the output, it always shows that the buffer is half full of what seems to be valid audio data, but half full of zeros.

Creating a buffer of half the normal size just threw an error, so I know it's actually storing zeros. It isn't just some weirdness with the buffer size. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Keep in mind that this is my first Android application, though I'm pretty familiar with Java.

Comment: Are you saying the first half contains what appears to be valid data and the last half is all zeros or is it 16 bits data, 16 bits zero, 16 bits data, 16 bits zero....and so on?

Comment: The first half is valid, and the second half is all zeros.

Comment: OK, I just had a dumb idea because it was recording in mono that every other 16 bits related to one channel of what would normally be stereo in an interleaved form. Sorry I haven't any other ideas (dumb or otherwise) - your code looks OK to me.

Comment: You may be confusing a size in bytes with a size in samples - typically 2 bytes each for mono (16bit) or 4 bytes for stereo.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, that's certainly something to consider. Do you see anything in the code I posted that looks to you like I've done that? I don't see anything, but I'm still new at this so I may be overlooking something.

Comment: Yes, for example where you create an array of shorts with the byte size as its number of 16-bit elements, that is an implicit doubling of size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think I may have solved this. I wrote this previously in C++ using Windows WaveIn and I used a short int array for the buffer, so I naturally tried to do that here. After reading the documentation again, though, it looks like I need a byte[] array. After changing it, it seems to work. Thanks for your help though, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem, I think it is because the:

- getMinBufferSize returns the size in bytes
- AudioRecord constructor accepts size in bytes.
- Read function is overloaded and can accept bytes & shorts. Your audioData variable is a short, so it is expecting buffersize in short also, only thing is that you are now specifying buffer size in bytes, so actually the buffersize specified is twice too big! (short = 2x byte)

What I did is dividing buffersize by 2 in the read function. It seems to solve it here, but I have to test it a bit better.

Hope this helps ;)

Cheers,

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `AudioRecord.read`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) seems to suggest that it returns the number of bytes read.  You don't seem to be doing anything with the return value of `AudioRecord.read`, so perhaps you are just reading past the end of the used buffer.

If you want to fill the buffer, change `AudioRecord.Read` to:

```
int offset = 0, read = 1;
while (offset < bufferSize)
{
    read = recorder.read(audioData, offset, bufferSize);
    offset += read;
    if (read <= 0) break;
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea. I just put it in my code, and now I get an ANR. This is crazy.

Comment: @AbernathyBeardevil, It would seem I had a typo.  That code would have gone into an infinite loop as I never incremented `offset`.  See the updated code above.

Comment: I updated the code and it no longer hangs, but it still returns a half-full, half-zero buffer. I notice, though, that recorder.read in my original code always returned 256 though the buffer was 512. Do you think that maybe just calling recorder.read() twice could do the trick? (of course starting the second time at the end of the first read)

Comment: Interesting: calling it with twice the buffer size returned all zeros.

Comment: I tried doubling, and subsequently tripling the size of the buffer. Each time exactly half is filled with zeros and exactly half is filled with valid values. Could this be a configuration mistake on my part? Could I, perhaps, have used incorrect parameters when creating my audiorecord object?

Comment: With any stream type situation, there is never a guarantee that the entire buffer will be used.  Is there a reason you want it to be?

Comment: I guess it doesn't need to be fully used, but it seems inefficient to create a buffer twice the size really needed. Also, if the buffer being half empty indicates that the microphone actually isn't recording half the data it should be (which I think it does), then it is a problem for me. My app is supposed to analyze recorded sound and detect frequencies among other things. If I'm missing half my data, it's going to be a problem.

Comment: I actually think I may have solved this. I wrote this person in C++ using Windows WaveIn and I used a short int array for the buffer, so I naturally tried to do that here. After reading the documentation again, though, it looks like I need a byte[] array. After changing it, it seems to work. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Wow. Typo. I wrote this previously in c++. Not person.